# What is phonetic transcription of "uses"

Tags: pronunciation, ipa, transcription

I don't know exact pronunciation of these words. It's hard for me to hear what sound there is "e", "ə" or "ɪ". And on the end I suppose there is "s", possibly "z"?

- verb "use" [juːz], third person form "uses" ?
- noun "use" [juːs], plural "uses" ?

What are UK pronunciations?

Comment: You are right that it is hard to hear.  The vowel sound is overpowered by the hard S on both sides.  Either `ˈjuz-əz` or `ˈjuz-ɪz` is fine.  These two vowels are very close together and in some dialects, the pronunciation is somewhat in between:  It's known as the "[pin-pen merger](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33259/which-dialects-pronounce-pen-as-pin)".

Comment: Thanks, but both are correct? Even there is a very little difference I prefer use correct sound.

Comment: @Nanigashi Yes, thank you for comment. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Where I come from (US English), "use" as a verb is [juːz], and the third person singular form of it ("uses") is [juːzəz]. For the noun: singular is [juːs], and plural is [juːsəz].

Comment: Thank you for response. Mainly I interested in UK pronunciation, but US is worth to know also.

Answer (score 0):

The phonetic transcription of 'uses' (third person singular) in British English is [ˈjuːzɪz] and that of 'uses' (plural noun) is [ˈjuːsɪz]. The pronunciation with [əz], as mentioned in Lorel C's answer, is dialectal.